# Application of time series analysis to Bitcoin prices

Tags: time-series, market-data, trading, bitcoin, blockchain

Various exchanges allow for the trading of Bitcoins. The price of Bitcoin was very volatile since the inception of the system, today it is 391.76 USD:

[image]

I wonder whether time series analysis tools from established financial markets can be applied to this market. Obviously the Bitcoin market is different - but maybe we see parallels.

This questions asks for personal experiences and mainly quant/math articles on the trading of Bitcoins.

Comment: If I were you I would check in the first place leading indicators for the BC price. For example see the paper [main drivers for BC price](http://arxiv.org/pdf/1406.0268.pdf). In the next step, conduct a variable selection process and check, which variables are the best to use in your model. Finally, I would select my time series model based on these characteristics. For example you could start with damped exp. smoothing, if if you detect a strong trend in your dependent variable or check out a multiple regression model. Finally, you could also use comb. forecasting to get a better result.